# FileInfo.Exists not reliable with UNC path

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I want to determine if a UNC file exists. I create a FileInfo object, then call FileInfo.Exists. But it'll occasionally return false, even if the file actually exists.

How can I accurately determine if a UNC file exists?

Comment: You might not have sufficient permission to check if the file exists.

Comment: I do have sufficient permission, FileInfo.Exists returns true 99% of the time, but the rest 1% is critical to my application. I guess it's caused by network latency, but FileInfo does not throw an exception to report this.

Comment: are you using ipv6 addressed in your unc path?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a general sense, because as Ben mentions, you might not have ACLs to see if it exists. That being said, the best way to determine if a file exists (based on your scenario) is to attempt to open the file